# How to update the date format in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, date, format

I have dates in the database with the format YYYYMMDD. But i would like to update them all to MM/DD/YYYYY.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no format stored in the [date/time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) data types. If you want an specific output format use the [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) function

```
select to_char(current_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

If the date column is text then first cast it to date to use the above function

```
select to_char(start_date::date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Thanks. But the interface doesnt support/show the current format of the date (YYYYMMDD) in the database. So i will have to update the date in the database to mm/dd/yyyy. I tried to update using  " Update <TableName> set start_date = to_char(current_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'); " .But it gives me the error " to_char(start_date, 'M... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." Can you please assist?

Comment: @user What is the interface? Are you sure you are using Postgresql? Do `select version()`

Comment: @user Is the `start_date` text? Post the output of `\d my_table`

Comment: Yes. Start_Date is a varchar.It is postgres 8.4

Comment: BELOW WORKED. THANKS A LOT.   select to_char(start_date::date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')